# локальные уведомления когда приложение свернуто

Tags: ios, swift

Интересует, как реализовать локальные уведомления когда приложение в бэкграунде, то есть у каждого уведомления есть такой метод (сначала идет подключение к `API`, которое меняется раз в минуту а потом наполнение) :

```
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = name
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 60, repeats:true)
                        UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    let reguest = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "identifier", content: content, trigger: trigger)
                        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(reguest) { (error) in}
```

, который работет раз в минуту когда приложение на экране, но как только сворачивается - то всё. Как создать метод в бэкграунде с периодичностью, допустим, раз в минуту?

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, речь идет именно о Нотификациях для пользователя или Фетч в бэкграунде?

Comment: Ну я пока что никогда не делал подобных нотификаций, поэтому могу ошибаться в концепции их создания. Насколько я понимаю в бекграунде приложение должно кинуть запрос на сервер и сравнить данные со своими, если они различаются то должно выскакивать уведомление. Фетч в бекграунде и нотификации разве не связанные между собой вещи?) Сорри за тупые вопросы

Comment: Перенесите логику на сервер и используйте обычные нотификации.

Comment: Вы каждую минуту шэдъюлите повторяющийся нотификешн который будет бомбить каждую минуту. Пачка повторяющихся уведомлений, растущая как снежный ком. Вы уверенны, что это именно тот результат который вам нужен?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приведенный вами код способен работать в бэкграунде. Скорее проблема в том, что ваше приложение в целом не работает в этом режиме. Как добиться чтобы работало? – читайте [документацию](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html).

В iOS в бэке можно делать ограниченное количество задач:

1. Кратковременно выполнять код после закрытия апа (вроде до 3 минут)
2. Скачивать/закачивать файл.
3. Проигрывать/записывать аудио.
4. Отслеживать геопозицию.
5. VoIP.
6. Регулярная скачка контента, типа новостных апов. (iOS сама решает, когда вы можете качать).
7. Блютуз и прочие внешние девайсы.

Причем каждый пункт имеет строгие ограничения. У вас не получится под видом проигрывания музыки скачивать данные о погоде (а раньше можно было).

Answer (score 0):

Читал несколько раз вопрос, так и не понял, какую задачу вы пытаетесь, хотите решить, плюс посмотрел ваши вопросы. 
Возможно вашей задачи подойдут Background Update Notification, в этой [документации](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH10-SW1) описание 
Единственное, что их не следует слишком часто посылать
Либо [почитайте](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) про работу в бэкграунде ios